# INSERT query with subquery: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I have this query that inserts rows, using a subquery like so:

```
INSERT INTO Lecture_presence_Student (`presence_id`, `Lecture_id`, `Student_id`, `status`) VALUES

(
 (
  SELECT '' as presence_id, Lecture.Lecture_id, CourseEdition_students_Student.Student_id, 'onverwerkt' 
  FROM
    CourseEdition_students_Student 
        INNER JOIN Lecture ON    CourseEdition_students_Student.CourseEdition_id = Lecture.CourseEdition_id



    )       
)
```

I don't get it, the sub select query returns 4 columns, the same number as the INSERT query. Why does it give me the error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your subselect returning more than one row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

instead of using `INSERT INTO VALUES`, use `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM`

```
INSERT INTO Lecture_presence_Student 
(
    `presence_id`
    , `Lecture_id`
    , `Student_id`
    , `status`
) 
SELECT '' as presence_id
    , Lecture.Lecture_id
    , CourseEdition_students_Student.Student_id
    , 'onverwerkt' 
FROM    CourseEdition_students_Student 
INNER JOIN Lecture 
    ON    CourseEdition_students_Student.CourseEdition_id = Lecture.CourseEdition_id
```

then if you get more than one record in your query, the `INSERT` will work.

Comment: Yes this did the trick. The Values clause had to be removed. Thanks all for the swift replies!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Lecture_presence_Student (`presence_id`, `Lecture_id`, `Student_id`, `status`) 
SELECT '' as presence_id, Lecture.Lecture_id, CourseEdition_students_Student.Student_id, 'onverwerkt' 
  FROM
    CourseEdition_students_Student 
        INNER JOIN Lecture ON    CourseEdition_students_Student.CourseEdition_id = Lecture.CourseEdition_id
```

and what for empty value for `presence_id`?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Lecture_presence_Student (`presence_id`, `Lecture_id`, `Student_id`, `status`) 

SELECT '', Lecture.Lecture_id, CourseEdition_students_Student.Student_id, 'onverwerkt' 
FROM
CourseEdition_students_Student 
    INNER JOIN Lecture ON    CourseEdition_students_Student.CourseEdition_id = Lecture.CourseEdition_id
```

Remove your "VALUES(())" and the alias won't be necessary.